How can I self-update & self-restart a Go application?
I have a Go application (lets call it A) who's responsibility is to basically:

Fetch latest upgrade for itself.
If new version available, update itself & restart.
Download a file & extract it (to keep it simple)

This app is being triggered by a shell script (say S) like ./A and the idea is to have all this logic within A itself.
I'm using go-selfupdate(https://github.com/sanbornm/go-selfupdate) for the self-update part of it but it does not do anything to restart the application (the hard part lol). I see CloudFlare tableflip(https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cloudflare/tableflip#section-readme) which can be used for http serving applications for graceful restarts, but A is not one.
Another approach I saw was to have A do exec.Command("A") and exit, essentially spawning a new process with the updated A and the original A dies. But I cannot do this since once the original A exits, S receives the exit code and proceeds and does not wait for A to perform it's actual functions.
On a similar note, I could exec.Command("A") from A and wait until the child process completes, but doesn't that use double the resources?
Adding a wrapper script to perform the restarts is a valid option but I would like A to be as self-sufficient as possible. I cannot necessarily add A as a systemctl process since S & A are downloaded on demand and run (during system upgrades). Also, S & A will always be running on a Linux based machine.
Any help is appreciated :)

You seem to be looking for syscall.ForkExec.

"but doesn't that use double the resources?" - if your program without doing anything specific uses so much memory that this would be actually a problem, you should be solving the high memory usage problem.

While I'm with Volker, I would suggest to look at using something more serious than a shell script to run your app. For instance, you can have a normal systemd service (note that systemd supports user-level services just fine) or a transient service (see systemd-run)—as they have a useful property of supporting systemctl restart.

In other words don't try to roll your own, use existing operating system services. That's really good advice, but Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service so the only correct answer to this question would be to hack something together in code. Because it specifically asks to do it in code.
